# How To Diag Perf Issues in MVC4/Razor cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a web page that is rendered from an MVC4 controller.  the controller is very fast, yet the page runs total request any wheres from 500ms to 30,000ms.  Exact same data processed and load on server similar.  When I make a trivial razor page that processes similar data it is reasonably fast (couple hundred ms).

So, the razor page is quite complex and hard to pull apart.  I tried putting a trace statement in the razor page but it does not seem to output anyplace I can find.  My question is, how can I analyze performance on a razor page?  Below are some stats from my app (using Glimpse) showing that the controller is fast, yet the page is slow.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bic7u9eja5fr2ct/k9d0uqcZXL

THanks,

Comment: i'd suggest using miniprofiler, that should allow you get a look at some of the page internals, you should also be able to add some tracing to sections of the page, and best of all, it's written by the folks here at SO

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at it with Fiddler ? http://fiddler2.com/

Sometimes a "page" pull many different ressources which we forget or just did not know about.

Once you see where the bottleneck is (are), you can optimize by bundling css and js, and eventually using a CDN. I have 2 blog posts about this.
Here is the first: http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/improve-loading-speed-for-an-asp-net-mvc-4-0-application-cache-bundling-minification/ and the 2nd: http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/improve-loading-speed-of-a-mvc-4-0-web-application/

Hope this help,
Bernard